# How to execute zookeeper-server-start .bat file from my java program?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to spin up zookeeper and kafka servers from my java code. We usually execute the batch files manually, I am trying to automate but the server never starts.

I have tried running other .bat files using the same code and they run like a charm but the zookeeper and kafka-server ones never execute successfully nor do they throw any error

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c",
    "C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/bin/windows/zookeeper-server-start.bat",
    "C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/config/zookeeper.properties"});
```

I want the zookeeper server to get started and remain started whereas it doesn't. Please help where am I going wrong, is this even possible?

Comment: Any special reason for trying to do it with Java ?

Comment: I am having trouble testing Kafka streams, using embedded kafka servers of which the documentation is pretty vague too. So I am planning to spin up my own local server for test purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below program worked for me, it will print all logs to console and will wait for the process to terminate:

```
import java.io.*;
public class ExecuteProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c",
                    "E:/Softwares/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/bin/windows/zookeeper-server-start.bat",
                    "E:/Softwares/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/config/zookeeper.properties"});
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh. Adding the "start" flag and providing absolute paths for both the files, seemed to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I exactly don't know why but adding the "start" flag made it work for me. Now I am able to run both the zookeeper and kafka servers from within the code. The code I am using is as follows,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start",
    "C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/bin/windows/zookeeper-server-start.bat",
    "C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/config/zookeeper.properties"});

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start",
    "C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/bin/windows/kafka-server-start.bat",
    "C:/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/config/server.properties"});
```